# error with inputting string using sc.nextLine

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GpaConverterTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    GpaConverter g = new GpaConverter();

    System.out.println("How many classes are you taking? ");
    int classAmount = sc.nextInt();
    while(classAmount > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Grade: ");
        String grade = sc.nextLine();
        g.setGpaValue(grade);
        classAmount--;
    }
    System.out.println("Average: " + g.getAverage());

}
}
```

My basic problem is that it wont let me enter in the grade string. This is what happens...

Output:
"How many classes are you taking? 
2
Enter Grade: 
Enter Grade: 
"
It does not let me enter in the grade string.
Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Use sc.next() instead of line.